# is it possible to create a dynamic case in sql?

Tags: sql

i have this statement in which i would fetch the grades of the students.

```
select concat(students.l_name,', ',students.f_name) as 'Student Name', 
max(case when test_info.test_num =1 then concat(test_results.score,'/',test_info.max_score) end) as 'Quiz #1', 
max(case when test_info.test_num =2 then concat(test_results.score,'/',test_info.max_score) end) as 'Quiz #2', 
max(case when test_info.test_num =3 then concat(test_results.score,'/',test_info.max_score) end) as 'Quiz #3'from test_results 
left join test_info on test_results.test_info_id = test_info.test_info_id 
left join students on test_results.stud_id = students.stud_id 
where test_info.test_type_id = 1 
group by test_results.stud_id order by students.l_name;
```

now my problem is that the number quizzes would eventually increase and i have to create another case statement for it to display all of the grades. is there any possible way in which the case statement would be created dynamically based on the current total number of quizzes?

Answer (score 0):

You wanted it as additional column isnt it? 
There is no dynamic in a sql. you may meed a PL/SQL if it is Oracle.

Also I feel, you can always include the test_info.test_num in your group by condition, so you need just one concat().

your updated Query. Now you get it in multiple rows.

```
select concat(students.l_name,', ',students.f_name) as 'Student Name', 
concat('Quiz #',test_info.test_num) as test_number,
MAX(concat(test_results.score,'/',test_info.max_score)) as  test_results 
left join test_info on test_results.test_info_id = test_info.test_info_id 
left join students on test_results.stud_id = students.stud_id 
where test_info.test_type_id = 1 
group by test_results.stud_id , test_info.test_num
order by students.l_name, test_info.test_num;
```